# Queryset working in regular django but getting KeyError when applying the queryset to a DRF Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I got the following queryset:

```
queryset = Expense.objects
.annotate(month=TruncMonth('expense_date'))
.values('month')
.annotate(total_cost=Sum('cost'))
.values('month', 'total_cost')
.order_by("month")
```

Which essentially sums all expense costs and groups them by month. If I just print out the queryset it works fine:

```
<QuerySet [{'month': datetime.date(2020, 9, 1), 'total_cost': Decimal('1029772.00')}]>
```

However, if I try to serializer it:

```
serializer = ExpenseSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

I get

```
Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `cost` on serializer `ExpenseSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'cost'."
```

`serializer.py`:

```
class ExpenseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        exclude = ("receipt", )
```

Whats the fuss?

Comment: Your queryset does not contain a `.cost`, since the `.values(..)` only will pass a `month` and `total_cost`. In other words your `ExpenseSerializer` is constructed to serialize `Expense` objects, not dictionaries of other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ExpenseSerializer` is constructed to serialize `Expense` objects, or dictionaries that contain all the necessary fields your `ExpenseSerializer` needs.

Your queryset however only passes two values: `month` and `total_cost`. You thus should not wrap it through an `ExpenseSerializer`, but for example a custom one like:

```
class ExpenseSummarySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    month = serializers.DateField()
    total_cost = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Hmm - I don't follow - how will this `ExpenseSummarySerializer` be connected to the Expense object then?

Edit: Aha and then I just pass it like `serializer = ExpenseSummarySerializer(queryset, many=True)`? I see

Comment: @erikvm: yes. Because your queryset does not generate `Expense` objects, it generates *dictionaries*.